# Detect DOM object vs. jQuery Object

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery

I have a function that I want to be able to allow passing in either a regular javascript DOM element object or a jQuery object. If its not yet a jQuery object I will then make it one.

Does anyone know of a very reliable way to detect this.

```
function functionName(elm){
   //Detect if elm is not a jquery object in condition
   if (elm) elm = $(elm);

}
```

A logical approach is to detect one of the properties of the DOM element object. The question is, which property would be the most reliable to detect?

I could also just make it a jquery object either way since jQuery doesn't have a problem with something like: $($imajQueryObjAlready); However, the purpose of this question is not to just solve the problem, but to find a good way to detect if its a DOM object vs. a jQuery object.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To test for a DOM element, you can check its `nodeType` property:

```
if( elm.nodeType ) {
    // Was a DOM node
}
```

or you could check the jQuery property:

```
if( elm.jquery ) {
    // Was a jQuery object
}
```

Comment: +1 Two excellent solutions -- I prefer the latter for legibility.

Comment: @lonesomeday - The only disclaimer I'd give (or should have given) is that it isn't part of the public API, [currently anyway](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7200), so jQuery could decide to remove that property someday. Doubtful though.

Comment: True. Of course, conversely, jQuery could decide to add a `nodeType` property!

Comment: function isJQuery( o ) { return null !== o && CS.object === typeof o && o.jquery; }

    function isDOM( o ) { return null !== o && CS.object === typeof o && o.nodeType; }

Answer (score 13):

To test for a jQuery object, you can use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if(elm instanceof jQuery) {
    ...
}
```

or:

```
if(elm instanceof $) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

jQuery does it like this:

```
if ( selector.nodeType )
```

(jQuery 1.4.3, line 109)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to simply pass it into the jQuery function either way.  If it's already a jQuery object, it will return it unchanged:

```
function(elem){
   elem = $(elem);
   ...
}
```

From the jQuery source code, this is what's happening:

```
if (selector.selector !== undefined) {
    this.selector = selector.selector;
    this.context = selector.context;
}

return jQuery.makeArray( selector, this );
```

Where makeArray is merging the new (default) jQuery object with the passed in one.

Comment: It isn't really unchanged. You're getting a new jQuery object. There could be side effects. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nu7D6/

Comment: @Patrick - No, you'll get the original jQuery object back if it is already a jQuery object. $(selector) === $($(selector)) always returns true.

Comment: @Patrick Take a look at my edit, where are the side effects introduced?

Comment: @James - Are you sure about that? See the example in my comment above. The example in your comment would definitely not be `===` since you're actually creating 3 completely unique objects.

Comment: @Patrick They are not the same object, but that doesn't mean that any side effect inducing operations are being done.  Take a look at the jQuery source code (or the excerpt in my answer).

Comment: @Zack - Side effect could come if you should need to do such an `===` comparison. Probably doesn't happen often. Another could be with the stored state of changes to the DOM elements that have happened. Using `.end()` may not take you back to a previous state. Haven't tested that though.

Comment: @Zack - I'm may be mistaken about `.end()`. The state doesn't seem to be saved, though I could have sworn that it was. Still testing.

Comment: @Patrick The point about a comparison failing is interesting, although I would point out that a statement like `$('html') === $('html')` will always be false as well, so I can't really see where it would be relevant.  I suppose if the function returned or stored the element, and the user expected it to compare correctly to the element passed in, but that seems like a very specific edge case.

Comment: @Zack - Yes, I do think it would be a very rare case where you're passing the objects around and need to verify what you have. It is going to be a faster operation to test a property though, if you're a stickler about performance. :o)

Comment: @Patrick Fair enough about the performance, but it would be premature optimization.  If your application is having performance problems, i'd bet you anything that wrapping the jQuery object is not the source :).

Comment: @Zack - Certainly not the source of anything major. Some of us are just a little obsessive. :o) [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Dfw5/) of what I was thinking of with `.end()`. There's no way to get back to the original set that the selector found if you create a new object by double-wrapping. Again, probably isn't often a problem, but could come up.

Comment: @Patrick The end issue is another improbable one, what sort of function (short of one injected into jQuery itself) could assume anything about your filter history to modify it?  I get the performance obsession, but there is an inverse correlation between readability and performance.

Comment: @Zack - Yes, these are somewhat remote, but I guess I wouldn't consider it to be quite so improbable if the function was part of a set of code where it could anticipate the possibility. In such a case, re-wrapping the object wouldn't be an option. Anyway, my only point was that you don't get an unchanged object. As far as readability vs performance, I agree. My philosophy is that's why we have code comments. ;o)

Comment: @Patrick Comments are great, but there's also the question of maintainability.  Take a listen to Stack Overflow podcast #83 for a great discussion of the issues with maintaining optimized code.

Comment: @Zack - I'll check it out. I had no idea that Stack Overflow had podcasts. Thanks for the reference. :o)

Comment: @Patrick - In Firebug, ($(document) === $($(document))) evaluates to true. Putting the same expression in an alert produces false. Very odd. I'll have to dig through the jQuery code and find out why...

Comment: @James - That's very strange. Firebug gives me `false`. Also gives me `false` for `($(document) === $(document))`. Sorry for this question, but is there any chance you have `prototypejs` or some other library loaded instead? `prototype` returns an unwrapped DOM element, which means you would ultimately be doing `document === document`.

Comment: @James - Ah, perhaps jQuery isn't loaded at all when you're testing it. It seems that Firebug uses `$` for its own purposes. If you type `$` into the console without a library loaded, it gives you a function `anonymous()`.

Answer (score 6):

`elm instanceof jQuery` is the most foolproof way, as testing `elm.nodeType` would mistake `{nodeType:1}` for a DOM element, and testing `elm.jquery` would mistake `{jquery:$()}` for a jQuery object, in addition to there being no guarantee future jQuery objects won't have a `jquery` property.

Answer (score 0):

The classy way:

```
function is_jquery_object(x) {
    return window.jQuery && x instanceof jQuery;
}

function is_dom_object(x) {
    return window.HTMLElement && x instanceof HTMLElement;
}
```

Building on @karim79's answer, if you need to be *sure* it's either a DOM or jQuery object, use these tests. (The `window` test helps the function fail gracefully if the class is not defined, e.g. jQuery failed to load.)