# Unwrap safely jQuery instances to get the wrapped DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Wrapping twice an HTML element with jQuery is a safe operation, since it returns an instance of the same DOM element:

```
var $a = $('#foo');
var $b = $($a);
alert($b.get(0) === $a.get(0)); // true
```

It allows a flexible setup of configuration objects, which may contain either selectors, or DOM elements, or jQuery instances.

I didn't know it, so in my personal library I extended jQuery with methods to safely wrap and unwrap objects.

Is there in the jQuery core a safe backward operation to unwrap DOM elements from their relative jQuery instances?

I mean something acting like that:

```
function unwrap(obj) {
    return (obj instanceof jQuery) ? obj.get(0) : obj;
}
```

which is smart enough to allow avoiding that conditional check each time.

Comment: jQuery can't be smarter than the underlying JavaScript engine itself.

Answer (score 1):

[Detect DOM object vs. jQuery Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140015/detect-dom-object-vs-jquery-object) seems to contain the answer to this question.

Each jQuery object has a jquery property. Something like:

```
function unwrap(obj) {
    return (obj.jquery) ? obj.get(0) : obj;
}
```

Comment: How is that better than `obj instanceof jQuery`? I think the OP's solution is better; it's immediately clear what's being evaluated (and is less error prone).

Comment: I understood the question to be asking for an alternative to the `intanceof` syntax.

Comment: `instanceof` has trouble working in cross frame environments, realistically, `obj[0]` instead of `obj.get(0)` is the only suggestion that I have on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to wrap everything in jQuery then just grab the 0th element out of the resulting array:

```
jQuery( elem )[0];
```

If passed a jQuery object, `jQuery( jQueryObject )` will return the same elements in the same order.  If you pass an element this returns the element.  If you pass a jQuery object, this will return the first element inside it.  If you pass a selector, this returns the first match in the DOM.

We use a similar technique in jQuery UI to basically resolve whatever selector/element/jquery object you passed in the options to a widget.

Comment: This makes sense and is much more concise, though the behavior is not *exactly* the same. This method will return either a DOM object for a valid selector string or `undefined` for an invalid selector string. The other method will return the string parameter itself.